# Dataframe Merge with match key in two different columns

Tags: python, pandas, merge, inner-join

I would like to `merge` two DataFrames, but the matching key in the 2nd DataFrame is scattered in two different columns. What is the best way to merge the two DF?

```
import pandas as pd

data1 = {'key': ['abc','efg', 'xyz', 'sdf']}
data2 = {'key1' : ['abc','sss','ggg','ccc'],
         'key2' : ['aaa','efg','xyz', 'sdf'],
         'msg' : ['happy','mad','smile','great']}

df1= pd.DataFrame(data1)
df2= pd.DataFrame(data2)
```

[image]

Comment: Are the keys sorted as in your example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

easiest way to fix this would be to melt the dataframe and merge the dataframes

```
data1 = {'key': ['abc','efg', 'xyz', 'sdf']}
data2 = {'key1' : ['abc','sss','ggg','ccc'],
         'key2' : ['aaa','efg','xyz', 'sdf'],
         'msg' : ['happy','mad','smile','great']}
data1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)
data2 = pd.DataFrame(data2).melt(id_vars='msg', value_name='key').drop('variable', axis=1)
df = data1.merge(data2, on='key')

df = 
    key msg
0   abc happy
1   efg mad
2   xyz smile
3   sdf great
```

Comment: Thanks. I cannot use melt because there are other columns in 2nd DataFrame (DF2) that I need to keep.

Comment: mention all the columns as a list in id_vars and the dataframe will melt only key columns. Let me know if that works

Answer (score 0):

If both dataframes have a relation where row1 of df1 corresponds to row1 of df2 and so on then you can simply merge on index.

Code:

```
df = pd.merge(df1, df2, left_index=True, right_index=True)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   key key1 key2    msg
0  abc  abc  aaa  happy
1  efg  sss  efg    mad
2  xyz  ggg  xyz  smile
3  sdf  ccc  sdf  great
```